# Error while inserting a clob data in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a stored procedure which accepts string as a parameter and it is assigned to a clob variable and used it in insert query.

Stored Procedure -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPROC(my_data VARCHAR2)   
AS
  my_clob clob;
BEGIN         
      my_clob := my_data; 
      INSERT INTO MYTABLE(MYCLOBCOL) values (my_clob);     
COMMIT;
END;
```

But while inserting large chunk of data it throws below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I changed the procedure to below but still I dint find it working,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPROC(my_data VARCHAR2)   
    AS
      my_clob clob;
    BEGIN         
          --my_clob := my_data; 
          SELECT CONCAT(my_clob, my_data) INTO my_clob FROM DUAL;
          INSERT INTO MYTABLE(MYCLOBCOL) values (my_clob);     
    COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: For large chunks (i.e., > 32k) you should use the dbms_lob package, procedure dbms_lob.append.

Comment: The error is not coming from the code *inside* the procedure; it is coming from the call *to* the procedure, because the string value you're passing (hopefully as a bind variable) is larger than the 32k allowed for the varchar2 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Both the comments above are valid depending on the version of Oracle and the programming language used to call the procedure.  I code with VB.NET (VS 2013) and when storing large text data I use CLOB as the parameter type in the call to the stored procedure and the stored procedure itself.  Assuming the java call can use the CLOB type, change the procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPROC(my_data CLOB)   
AS
BEGIN         
      INSERT INTO MYTABLE(MYCLOBCOL) values (my_data);     
COMMIT;
END;
```

Varchar2 is limited to 4000 characters, CLOB is, depending on database version, limited to 2gb.